Cellspacing and cellpadding in HTML
I want to know about cellspacing and cellpadding in HTML
I was coding in vscode so when i tried typing cellspacing it didn't show me as a table attribute.I just started learning HTML so can someone help me in this.
This is what I mean
Same problem for cellpadding too. Is there any other way to do this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#cellpadding

this would also be a good opportunity to learn about CSS. Unless you need inline style for email-templates than you would make your life much easier when simply adding styles to a CSS file.

cellpadding is deprecated obsolete, that's why it won't show up in vscode.

Defines the space between the content of a cell and its border. This attribute is obsolete: instead of using it, apply the padding CSS property to the <th> and <td> elements.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#cellpadding

To be pedantic, it's now marked obsolete and not just deprecated.

@Rob Thank you for pointing that out, I modified my answer a bit.

cellpadding attribute is used to set padding between cells.
Same as style padding :
td {
   padding: 10px;
}



<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>



while cellspacing attribute is used to set space between cells.


<table border="1" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>



cellpadding and cellspacing attribute in single code.


<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>



